# Extending community extensions - Helper/Data.php

Tags: extensions, helper

I'm planning to extend a community extension by creating relevant files in `app/code/local/myname/myext`. The community extension has multiple files that I want to customise but let's start simply. How would I implement the local equivalent of `Helper/Data.php`, even just to show it's working?

For example the community extension is like

```
class Compasser_Diogenes_Helper_Data extends Mage_Payment_Helper_Data
{
    //
    public function startDiogenes($cId, $stId, $shId, $mCode)
    {
        // working code is here, can output to log files
```

My local file is just trying to prove it's getting called. `app/code/local/Kaska/Diogenesext/Helper/Data.php`

```
include_once 'Compasser/Diogenes/Helper/Data.php';
// I also tried require_once Mage::getConfig()->getModuleDir('Helper', 'Diogenes') . '/Data.php';

class Kaska_Diogenesext_Helper_Data extends Compasser_Diogenes_Helper_Data
{

    public function startDiogenes($cId, $stId, $shId, $mCode)
    {

        Mage::log('test', null, 'test.log');
```

This is `app/code/local/Kaska/Diogenesext/etc/config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Kaska_Diogenesext>
        <version>0.0.1</version>
    </Kaska_Diogenesext>
</modules>
<global>
    <helpers>
        <kaska_diogenesext>
            <rewrite>
                <data>Kaska_Diogenesext_Helper</data>
            </rewrite>
        </kaska_diogenesext>
    </helpers>
```

This is the what's in the `app/etc/modules/Kaska_Diogenesext.xml` file. It's showing as enabled in admin.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Kaska_Diogenesext>
        <active>true</active>
        <codePool>local</codePool>
        <depends>
            <Compasser_Diogenes></Compasser_Diogenes>
        </depends>
    </Kaska_Diogenesext>
</modules>
```

In my log files I just see the community extension working, there's nothing from the local extension, nothing in `test.log` and no errors either. Cache not enabled but flushed anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to include the helper from Compasser because helpers are autoloaded (you have to include only controllers if you like to extend them). Also in your **config.xml** please try to change `<kaska_diogenesext>` to `<compasser_diogenes>` and `<data>Kaska_Diogenesext_Helper</data>` to `<data>Kaska_Diogenesext_Helper_Data</data>`.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the other answers that cover your syntax errors:

**Something that is often overlooked:** If you don't want to break translations of the module, be sure to make the module name explicit, otherwise it is automatically detected based on the class name and Magento will try to load translations from your own module instead of from the original. This *will* result in missing translations in developer mode and *can* result in translation conflicts in production.

To do so, simply add the following line to your rewritten helper:

```
protected $_moduleName = 'Kaska_Diogenesext';
```

where `Kaska_Diogenesext` is the name of the original extension, as in its class names.

Answer (score 1):

There are some mistake you have doing in code:

- Class rewrite is not proper. In  tag  `kaska_diogenesext` is
  wrong,it should be  **Compasser_Diogenes** module `helpers class prefix identifier .`

For getting `Compasser_Diogenes`  helper  classes prefix /identifier ,you  need goto `Compasser/Diogenes/etc/config.xml`.Here you can find helper between  tag.

```
<global>
    <helpers>
        <diogenes> <!-- i Guss that Compasser_Diogenes helper prefix/ identifer is diogenes -->
                <class>Compasser_Diogenes_Helper</class>
        </diogenes>
    </helpers>
    .....
```

**Now    Final is app/code/local/Kaska/Diogenesext/etc/config.xml**

```
<global>
......
    <helpers>
        <diogenes> <!--  kaska_diogenesext  change to  diogenes -->
            <rewrite>
                <data>Kaska_Diogenesext_Helper</data>
            </rewrite>
        </diogenes>
    </helpers>
```

- As it have `rewrite  helper class` ,you does not need to include the
  parent class().Magento **auto loader** automatically include
  `Compasser/Diogenes/Helper/Data.php;`So delete include_once **'Compasser/Diogenes/Helper/Data.php'**;

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I had to tweak it a bit to get it right - Kaska_Diogenesext_Helper_Data (as per Michael's answer below)

Answer (score 0):

Here i am show you how to Extend community Or third party module helper class in your own modules.
Now here i am extend asmaty extension helper.

1. create your module register xml  `app/etc/modules/Myextend_Shopbyextend.xml`

   `<?xml version="1.0"?>
   <config>
       <modules>
           <Myextend_Shopbyextend>
               <active>true</active>
               <codePool>local</codePool>
               <depends>
                   <Amasty_Shopby />
               </depends>
           </Myextend_Shopbyextend>
       </modules>
   </config>`
2. create module `config.xml` file `app/code/local/Myextend/Shopbyextend/etc/`

`<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
   <modules>
       <Myextend_Shopbyextend> 
           <version>0.1.0</version>
       </Myextend_Shopbyextend>
   </modules>
   <global>
        <helpers>
           <shopbyextend>
               <class>Myextend_Shopbyextend_Helper</class>
           </shopbyextend>
           <amshopby>
               <rewrite>
                   <data>Myextend_Shopbyextend_Helper_Data</data> 
               </rewrite>
           </amshopby>
        </helpers>

   </global>
</config>`

3. Last create your help file `app/code/local/Plumtree/Shopbyextend/Helper/Data.php` and extends Amasty_Shopby_Helper_Data class

`class Plumtree_Shopbyextend_Helper_Data extends Amasty_Shopby_Helper_Data
{
  public function getCurrentCategory()
    { 
          \\ Write your code here 
    }
}`

I hope this will help you